# How to use the FTP protocol in C?

Tags: c

I'm planning to study sockets using C language, and I want to create a basic FTP client. My question is where should I start reading about FTP protocol for socket programming in C?

And could you please give some FTP library for C language. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are trying to learn stuff, just read the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) and write code. If you are developing  software for serious purposes, use an existing, well-tested library. My recommendation is [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). If you don't want to use a library, just spawn an instance of [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) from your C program and talk to it over [pipes](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html). That way you will also learn to program pipes in C, along with sockets!

Comment: i will look the libcurl and your suggestions. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

My personal favorites

[Wikipedia for FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)

[Beej's Guide to Network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html)

Answer (score 5):

You should probably use a library for this rather than reinventing the wheel, what library to use depends on your platform. Is there any reason you need to use C rather than a higher level language, or do you just want an exercise to learn about socket programming with C?

Others have recommended [libCurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), it has implementations in heaps of other languages as well. I would add [ftplib](http://nbpfaus.net/~pfau/ftplib/ftplib.html) and [libftp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libftp/) (currently stopped) to that list. All are FOSS so great for study.

Comment: He states he wants to study, not to write an application.

Comment: yup i just want to study the FTP protocol but i think its nice if you have any suggestions for a FTP library for C. Thanks

Comment: look into curl if you wanna easy implementation ...

Comment: writing a hello world type app is probably the best way to study, especially for a language like C

Answer (score 5):

Protocol definition is [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/) and for socket programming [Beej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) is very nice.

Answer (score 3):

For documentation on FTP, there's a few relevant RFCs. They're dry but useful.

- http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt
- http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt
- http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2228.txt
- http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3659.txt

For a more accessible protocol discussion, check out http://cr.yp.to/ftp.html

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to FTP really causes some headache for me. I do not know if the following link is useful. I happen to see it.

http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/read-files-on-ftphttp/

The program does not seem too long. Hope helpful to you.